# Python - Checking whether any of multiple conditions are true

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, any

I am trying to modify a list in place to remove entries where the file extension does not match. I got this working by writing multiple 'or' conditions

```
from os import listdir
image_extensions = ['jpg','.png']

files = listdir('/home')
files = [x for x in files if '.jpg' in x or '.png' in x]

print files
```

I would like to have this use the image_extensions variable so that I can easily add more conditions. The latest thing I tried fails with the "requires string as left operand, not list":

```
from os import listdir
image_extensions = ['jpg','.png']

files = listdir('/home')
files = [x for x in files if any(s for s in image_extensions in x)]

print files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
files = [x for x in files if any(s in x for s in image_extensions)]
#                                |<-->|
```

Check if *any* of the extensions is contained in the file name `x`

Comment: This works beautifully! Now that I see it written out the right way, it makes sense!

Comment: Remember to accept this answer if you feel this is the best answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to that:

```
>>> filter(lambda f: filter(f.endswith, image_extensions), files)
```

Time profiling this expression compared to the previous answer, reveals that there is a bit of improvement on the previous one:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit("import os;l = os.listdir('.');ext = ['txt', 'ini', 'cfg'];filter(lambda f: filter(f.endswith, ext), l)", number=10000)
0.6541688442230225
>>> 
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit("import os;l = os.listdir('.');ext = ['txt', 'ini', 'cfg'];files=[x for x in l if any(s in x for s in ext)]", number=10000)
0.64410400390625
>>>
```